# How Can I Replace My 'Section' and 'Article' tags With Div's?

Tags: css

Live Preview: https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/InteractiveMap/index.html#Norway

I am having difficulties replacing my 'Article' and 'Section' tags with div's. All my attempts so far have ended up making things look weird and whatnot.

I think it's a bit big to make a JSFiddle for this, however my CSS file is very tidy and you can view it here: https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/css/InteractiveMap.css

One last thing, of which I have only just noticed. My Caret up and down symbols in my CSS file are showing up as â–¼ for Caret down and â–² for Caret up. What can I replace these with so you can see an up and down symbol when looking at my source code in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On â–¼ and â–²**

You have to change the browser encoding of your css files.
If you use Chrome, you can go to `Settings -> Tools -> Encoding -> UTF8`. It's very similar in other browsers.

To make utf8 default, put the following line at the very top of your css script:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

I can replace `<article>` and `<section>` with `<div>` without any problems over here.

Comment: Thank you for your very interesting response. You may have just been answering my question, however I have never learnt about encoding. Regarding the div's; Could you please share what styling you gave to them as my attempts have just failed and I believe there is some default browser code behind both tags of which removes when I try to replace them for div's. Best Regards, Tim

Comment: @TimMarshall I didn't give them any styling. I just replaced article and section by div.

Comment: Are  you using Google Chrome? I have uploaded a version with replaced tags for div's; https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/InteractiveMap/Replaced-With-Divs.html, of which makes the content above the slider unselectable and some sort of overlay on.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to get rid of these HTML5 tags so that your site works in older browsers? You can use a polyfill JavaScript library like [Modernizr](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://modernizr.com/&ei=3J1WUYS3NYq3iQej7ICYCw&usg=AFQjCNHnp4LYQuGIgYW80UV8Lh2xGOqP-w&bvm=bv.44442042,d.aGc) which fixes the bugs in older browsers so you can use the HTML5 semantic tags with good compatibility.

Comment: I don't believe I have any HTML5 tags on the page I have attached to my question starter. Best Regards, Tim.